# How do i close instance of NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I'm learning some obj-c and therefore i'm building a small cocoa application.

From the MainMenu.xib i have added a menu to the "Main menu" in the top. When click, this triggers a IBAction that opens an instance of a window, in this case a window for managing categories.

This category window has a NSWindowController, looks like this:

```
//  CategoriesWindow.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface CategoriesWindow : NSWindowController
-(IBAction)OpenCategoriesWindow:(id)sender;
@end

//  CategoriesWindow.m
#import "CategoriesWindow.h"

@implementation CategoriesWindow

-(IBAction)OpenCategoriesWindow:(id)sender
{
    CategoriesWindow *Categories = [[CategoriesWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"CategoriesWindow"];
    [Categories showWindow:self];
}
@end
```

To this i have a CategoriesWindow.xib with a NSTableView that does some things, so there for i have a CategoryTableController.h and .m that handles the data for this table.
When i hit a button i want it to do a bunch of things, and then i want the window to close it self. That is, i want this window to close itself from a IBAction in the CategoryTableController.m.

How do I do this? One bad thing with this setup (followed from a tutorial somewhere...) is that I can open a lots of instances of this window by clicking the menu-button.

Any tips or ideas where to begin?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware of this, but by making your  -(IBAction)OpenCategoriesWindow:(id)sender method an instance method of that same class, you've got a weird (erroneous) behaviour where one instance immediately creates another... this is likely leading to the odd behaviour you're observing. The solution is probably quite simple, and it's to just move that method into another class, probably the app delegate class.

Answer (score 0):

From there [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/close):

```
[Categories close];
```

However there is something wrong with your implementation as you are creating an instance of the class from an instance method of the class.  That doesn't look right to me.  Also you aren't retaining the new instance anywhere, so it will be possibly destroyed under ARC or leaked under MRR.

I think you might want:

```
-(IBAction)OpenCategoriesWindow:(id)sender
{
    [self showWindow:sender];
}

-(IBAction)CloseCategoriesWindow:(id)sender
{
    [self close];
}
```

Although I can't be sure.

Comment: I can't reach the instance Categories from the other file, since this is created on the action click.
The other case; the sender in this case, is'nt that the menu button? Can i set a value to this button some where to set this button as a named window or something like that?

Comment: @gubbfett The sender isn't important here.  I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: Ok, i tried to change the OpenCategoriesWindow to [self showWindow:sender] and nothing happens. No window is opening. How would that IBAction know that it would open that category window, when this action is called from a menu-button?

Comment: @gubbfett Because it's a method **within** `CategoriesWindow` (according to your code) and `NSWindowController`'s cannot be properly initialised without an associated window or NIB.